# Classic ASP equivalent curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 0);

Tags: php, ssl, asp-classic

I have an old ASP page which consumes https web service. I was told that web service is moving to a more secure SSL version and they wanted me to comsume web service by using a different parameter for SSL.

They send me a php sample code as you can see below;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 0);
```

How can I set this parameter using Classical ASP?

Thanks

Comment: to get help with ASP code you should post your ASP code so folks can get the gist of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do that at ASP page level, but you can configure your IIS host to accept a fixed list of ciphersuites.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1063215.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030